# Unknown file attribute 3

Tags: android, linux, flutter, sdk, zsh

I am new to linux and don't know much about its commands. I am trying to install flutter in wsl2 using zsh. So i am following the steps of this article https://medium.joshkautz.com/installing-flutter-2-0-on-wsl2-2fbf0a354c78
Everything went fine but the reach the step of moving the command line tools to the new version directory zsh gave me `unknown file attribute : 3` error.....anyone know what is this about and how to fix it.

Comment: Don't post links.  Copy and paste the command and error as text into your question.

Comment: @stark i am sorry about that...... i am mentioning the command i used along with screenshot

Comment: Post the command, so that we can see what you have entered to get this error message.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

`mv -vt $HOME/Applications/android/cmdline-tools/$($HOME/Applications/android/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$HOME/Applications/android --version | head -n1)/ $HOME/Applications/android/cmdline-tools/!($($HOME/Applications/android/cmdline-tools/bin/sdkmanager --sdk_root=$HOME/Applications/android --version | head -n1))`

This was the command i use and it is giving the error as shown in screenshot

Comment: Your command looks like it is written for bash shell.

Comment: Will this command work if i directly use the ubuntu bash shell??......i know it's total dumb question but what is bash shell??

Comment: There are several different shell languages hanging around (bash, ksh, zsh, tcsh, tclsh, ...). Everyone has his favorable one. You need to make up whith one you are going to use. As for your command, I don't understand why you posted this as an *answer*, because it does not answer anything, but because there are many substitutions going on in this command, I would do a `set -x` before running it, and then post the output.